# horizontal alignment of cubes

Tags: html, css, css-float

how to move the search icon cube and your files cube adjacent to the inventory cube....
i gave floats in firebug but nothing is working....
providing my fiddle below......

http://jsfiddle.net/B49Ap/15/

http://jsfiddle.net/B49Ap/15/embedded/result/

providing my code below

```
<div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                    <div class="desktopContactImage" data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;"
                    data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png">desktopImage</div>
                    <p style='clear: left; text-align:left;'>rajkumar</p>
                    <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;"
                    data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/search.png"></div>
                    <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;"
                    data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/yourfiles.png"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p style='clear: left; text-align:left;'>rajkumar</p>`

This element is messing with you. The `p` tag puts new lines before and after it. So remove it or just put it after the cubes and you'll just have to put some margins and padding to align our cubes properly.

I can update your jsfiddle if you want to see what I'm talking about. :)

I hope I helped.

Comment: i need to give title for each cube under it....so that only i am using p tag...like this http://jsfiddle.net/B49Ap/17/

Comment: Put the `p` and the cube in one div than float this div. (Every div should have a cube and a heading to the cube in it) That should do the work.

Comment: if i do it in such a way the cube is not showing up http://jsfiddle.net/B49Ap/19/

Comment: I don't know how this cubes work .. I saw they are not showing. See this http://jsfiddle.net/B49Ap/20/ It's not the best but I think it works for you. I suggest for easiest use table with two rows .. one for the cubes and one for the headings

Comment: thanks for your reply but the heading should come below the cube not above the cube

Comment: Than table is your solution :)